# How to throw explosives, e.g. a grenade in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I have some grenades, and molotov cocktails.

Yet I cannot throw them. I have them in my favorite list, yet selecting them does nothing. How am I supposed to throw them? And can I throw them in VATS menu?

I'm playing using the XBOX 360 controller.

Comment: I'd also like to know how you can throw grenades in VATS.. I haven't figured it out yet. I'm worried you can't, since you can't equip grenades as a primary weapon..

Comment: As simple a question as this seems, I found the game changed the mechanic and offered no explanation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Select your favorite explosive, and hold down your *melee button* for a while. You should hear a clicking noise on success before throwing.

The defaults are:

- XBOX: `RB`
- PS4: `R1`
- PC: <kbd>Alt</kbd>

After releasing, you throw the explosives. It seems you can hold grenades for a long while.

If you do a melee attack, try holding it longer. As soon as you have run out of grenades, pressing and holding the button will trigger a melee attack even if you are standing miles away from a foe.

I haven't figured out how to throw them in VATS mode; it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: It would be really nice to throw them in VATS, but the explosion radius seems larger than in previous games, so you don't have to be as accurate.

Comment: And for PS4, it's R1.

Comment: When a grenade is ready to be thrown you should hear a "click" sound. It doesn't seem to count down to detonation until you throw it though

Comment: Bummer that we can't cook our grenades. I mean, it's nice that we get however long we need (combat conditions allowing) to aim. But I still love it when a frag drops at the enemy's feet and they have no time to run - or, even more fun, bursts in the air overhead of a small group.

Comment: Although you can't throw them in VATS, if you get Demolition Expert 2 you can see a throwing arc showing you exactly where they will land. This is incredibly useful. It shows you if the grenade will make it through a window or not as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw them in VATS. Unequip all weapons, including grenades. Then only equip the grenades. Have your character unholster so that the grenade is showing in his hand. Now you can use the regular trigger button to use a grenade and throw them in VATS. I've only done this with frags so I'm not sure if it'll work on the others, but it should.

Comment: I will be trying this

Comment: This makes you punch in VATS

Comment: It doesn't make you punch in vats if you have the grenade equipped so it's showing in your hand. I do this all the time.

Comment: This makes you punch. You can't equip the grenade so it shows in your hand. You might be thinking of previous Fallout games, where your description is accurate.